# Is init a special reserved keyword for Javascript Object Literals?

Tags: javascript, ruby, class, initialization, object-literal

I ran across the following Javascript code.

```
var Zoo = {
 animals: [],

 init: function (animal_list) {
   for (i = 0; i < animal_list.length; i++) {
     this.animals.push(animal_list[i]);
   }
}
```

It looks like the init key maps to an executable function. That function takes in an animal list each item in the list into an animal array.

If I were in my native tongue Ruby, I would do something like this:

```
class Zoo
    def initialize animal_list
       @animals = animal_list  #animal_list is an array
    end
end
```

So is init the javascript equivalent of an initialize function? In ruby, I can call

```
my_ruby_zoo = Zoo.new ["lions", "tigers", "bears"]
```

In javascript, does the init function map to

```
var my_javascript_zoo = Zoo.new( ["lions", "tigers", "bears"]);
```

Comment: No; that's just a function.  Like any other function, it will run if you call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is init a special reserved keyword for Javascript Object Literals?

No, not at all. There is no pre-named function for initialization in JavaScript. Typically, if you have need of a "class" of objects in JavaScript, you use a constructor function with the `new` keyword:

```js
function Person(first, last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
}

// Usage:
var chuck = new Person("Charles", "Foreman");
```

You might then add functions that all instances created via `new Person` can use, by adding them as properties to the prototype that gets assigned to objects created via `new Person` (that prototype is taken from the `Person.prototype` property):

```js
Person.prototype.getFullName = function() {
    return this.first + " " + this.last;
};
```

Because this is a bit long-winded and handling inheritance hierarchies is more effort than it is in other languages (something that's being fixed in ES6), there are a lot of libraries out there that provide helper functions to hook things up for you. (Mine is called [`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/), there's also Resig's [Really Simple Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/), PrototypeJS's [`Class`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Class/), etc.) Some of these *helper scripts* may give certain function names special meaning. For instance, in both `Lineage` and PrototypeJS's `Class`, a function called `initialize` is special. (I've seen some where `ctor` was special.)

But not within JavaScript itself.

Your `Zoo` might look like this:

```js
function Zoo(animal_list) {
    this.animals = animal_list.slice(0); // Copy the array
}
```

If you want to add functions available on all `Zoo` instances, typically you'd add them to the prototype assigned by `new Zoo`:

```js
Zoo.prototype.showAll = function() {
    this.animals.forEach(function(animal) {
        console.log(animal);
    });
};

// Usage:
var z = new Zoo(['Tortoise', 'Emu', 'Lion']);
z.showAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your Zoo class a constructor it should be a function instead of an object literal:

```
var Zoo = function(animal_list) {
 this.animals = [];

 for (i = 0; i < animal_list.length; i++) {
   this.animals.push(animal_list[i]);
 }
}

var myZoo = new Zoo(["lions", "tigers", "bears"]);
```